# Time out php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress market place, we want to use a php function to update woocommerce products from a csv file on a ftp.

```
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
function UpdateStock()
{
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    set_time_limit(10000); //temps limite d'éxecution du code
    
    $filename = "path to csv file on a ftp"; //chemin vers le fichier csv du serveur ftp
   
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $ligne[] = fgetcsv($handle, ',');

    }
  
    fclose($handle);
    $woocommerce = new Client(
    
        // Your store URL
      // Your consumer key
       // Your consumer secret
        [
            'wp_api' => true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
            'version' => 'wc/v3', // WooCommerce WP REST API version
            'query_string_auth' => true,
            'verify_ssl' => false
        ]
    );
     for ($item = 1; $item < count($ligne); $item++) {
        $cell = $ligne[$item];
         if ($cell[13] == "0") {       //change la valeur 0 en outofstock
            $statue = "outofstock";
        } elseif ($cell[13] == "1") {
            $statue = "instock";
        } elseif ($cell[13] == "backorder") {
            $statue = "onbackorder";
        } else {
            $statue = "outofstock";
        }


     if ($cell[1] == "simple") { // vérifie si le produit est un produit simple

            $data = [ //récupère les données descriptions, stoc_status, short description
                "description" => $cell[7],
                "name" => $cell[3],
                "stock_status" => $statue,
                "Short description" => $cell[8],
                "regular_price" => $cell[25],
                "sale_price" => $cell[24]
            
            ];
            try {
                $woocommerce->put('products/' . $cell[0], $data); // ajoute les données récupérées au produits
            } catch (Exception $e) {//si les infos n'ont pas été importés, affiche le message d'erreur
                echo 'une erreur est survenue à l article ' . $cell[0] . '</br>'; 
            }


        } else {
            $data = [
                "description" => $cell[7],
                "name" => $cell[3],
                "stock_status" => $statue,
                "regular_price" => $cell[25],
                "sale_price" => $cell[24]
            ];
            $path = 'products/' . $cell[43]. '/variations/'.$cell[0];
            echo $path;
            try {
                $woocommerce->put($path, $data);

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'une erreur est survenue à l article ' . $cell[0] . '</br>';
            }

        }
        
    }

}
?>
```

Thing is the function runs for 5 min and just stops.
I installed a plugin to check php settings and it says that max_execution_time is set to 0.

What is the problem ? Thanks

[php settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq8Ae.png)

Comment: I think it is possible to override the cPanel PHP settings.
you need to check your PHP setting with server administrator.

Comment: Well they said it's limited to 360seconds, but 6min is a lot to check a 1.8Mb Csv isn't it ?